# Same URL for both HTML and JSON response

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am wondering if it's a good practice to use the same URL to provide both the HTML and JSON response.

For example if I am building a blog and I have a URL that provides the latest items, I would have a URL like /latest 
I would like to use the same URL for my endpoint in angular to retrieve the items so I have following route in my node implementation:

```
app.get("/latest",function(req,res){
    var type = req.header("Accept");
    if(type.indexOf("application/json") > -1){
        getLatestItems(req,res);
    }
    else {
        res.render("/latest", {user: req.session.username, current: "latest"});
    }

});
```

I was wondering if this approach is OK or is it better to have a separate set of endpoints for my JSON responses?

Comment: The `Accept` header can contain multiple mime types, and if you wanted to go this way the very _least_ you should do is check the `q` (quality) value. And after doing that, you’d still have to pay attention to issues like proxies caching the request and serving it to different clients, so you would have to specify when a cached copy might be used and when not, etc.

Comment: I think it is not really a good idea for a service that caters in part to such unpredictable clients as common “browsers” are – if this was an API where you could impose very specific rules on the requesting clients, that would be different.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a separate URL pattern for your backing API.

So in Angular you can still have a URL route `/latest`, but you will provide the JSON data via a URL like `/api/latest`.

This will create less confusion and also allow you to easily integrate the API with other stuff since it will only be returning JSON.